# Office.context.mailbox.item.getSelectedDataAsync is not returning the selected data in installed outlook

Tags: outlook, ms-office, office-js, office-js-helpers

As per the documentation provided, 
`Office.context.mailbox.item.getSelectedDataAsync(Office.CoercionType.Text, {}, getCallback)` supposed to return selected data from body or subject of the mailbox. instead the `callback` is returning some html markup in `asyncResult.value.data`, this issue is only in installed outlook.

However this works fine in browser application and it returns the selected data in `asyncResult.value.data` correctly.

Can someone explain to me why this issue occurs only in installed outlook? Probably I might be missing something, please clarify.

**html markup returned instead of selected data:**

```
"<html>\r\n\r\n<head>\r\n<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\">\r\n<meta name=Generator content=\"Microsoft Word 15 (filtered)\">\r\n<style>\r\n<!--\r\n /* Font Definitions */\r\n @font-face\r\n\t{font-family:\"Cambria Math\";\r\n\tpanose-1:2 4 5 3 5 4 6 3 2 4;}\r\n@font-face\r\n\t{font-family:Calibri;\r\n\tpanose-1:2 15 5 2 2 2 4 3 2 4;}\r\n /* Style Definitions */\r\n p.MsoNormal, li.MsoNormal, div.MsoNormal\r\n\t{margin:0cm;\r\n\tmargin-bottom:.0001pt;\r\n\tfont-size:11.0pt;\r\n\tfont-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif;}\r\na:link, span.MsoHyperlink\r\n\t{color:#0563C1;\r\n\ttext-decoration:underline;}\r\na:visited, span.MsoHyperlinkFollowed\r\n\t{color:#954F72;\r\n\ttext-decoration:underline;}\r\nspan.EmailStyle17\r\n\t{font-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif;\r\n\tcolor:windowtext;}\r\n.MsoChpDefault\r\n\t{font-family:\"Calibri\",sans-serif;}\r\n@page WordSection1\r\n\t{size:612.0pt 792.0pt;\r\n\tmargin:72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt 72.0pt;}\r\ndiv.WordSection1\r\n\t{page:WordSection1;}\r\n-->\r\n</style>\r\n\r\n</head>\r\n\r\n<body lang=EN-IN link=\"#0563C1\" vlink=\"#954F72\">\r\n\r\n<div class=WordSection1>\r\n\r\n<p class=MsoNormal>dheeerldfjshfjdsfs</p>\r\n\r\n</div>\r\n\r\n</body>\r\n\r\n</html>\r\n"
```

**screenshot for reference:**

[image: asyncresult]

Comment: @Vinh VO, what's your version number for Outlook? I cannot reproduce this here. However, I get the markup if I set my coercion type to Office.CoercionType.Html. During your debugging, did you check to see if your app's JavaScript was making the call with Office.CoercionType.Text?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't ask this question, it's the OP. I just edit it showing the screenshot (since the OP didn't have enough rep to make it visible)

Comment: Thanks Vinh VO. Apologies.
@sudheer reddy, can you kindly respond to my previous comment above?

Comment: Thanks @MSFT. I tried changing coercion type to Office.CoercionType.Text, its working now. Earlier the coercion type was Office.CoercionType.Html and it was working fine in web application, so I assumed that it will work in installed outlook as well. Anyways thanks alot MSFT for clarifying this.

Comment: Thanks @sudheerreddy  
I have promoted the comment to an answer so that you can mark this issue as correctly answered/solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer, as @sudheer reddy has confirmed it.

During your debugging, did you check to see if your app's JavaScript was making the call with Office.CoercionType.Text? If not, change your coercion type accordingly.